# Assigning multiple users to a workflow task

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, multiple-values

In a SharePoint 2013 workflow - I have an initiation Parameter called "Reviewer"  this is a Person or Group type and it is set to allow multiple values.

I have the task participants set to the parameter and to start in parallel. However, when I run the workflow only the last name in the list gets the task.

I want the workflow initiator to be able to add the names of reviewers at the start of the workflow. The list is not always the same people and they are not always in a group.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using initiation parameter and not the list column with person or group as data type and multiple selection is allowed?